# Site min-height 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website that I want to have a minimum height of 100%, so if there's not too much content on the page, the footer will be at the bottom of the page.
If there's more content, it will simply expand.

I used a website that has this as an example, and changed it to my needs. 
At first it seemed to work great, but now it's showing two problems: 
- The site always seems to be a bit more than 100% height; a small part extends beyond the screen.
- The footer isn't displayed at the bottom, but rather somewhere in the middle, despite having set the Bottom property.

This is the markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="Site.Master.vb" Inherits="Site" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head id="Head" runat="server">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Site (b&egrave;ta)</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server" autocomplete="off" class="formCss">
            <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="Toolscriptmanager1" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true">
                <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery.curvycorners.packed.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/Site.jquery.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery.colorize-1.3.1.js" />
                </Scripts>
            </ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
            <asp:Label ID="ContentTitle" runat="server" CssClass="content_title"></asp:Label>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="headerContainer">
                    <div id="header">
                        <telerik:RadMenu ID="HoofdMenu" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Height="20px" EnableImageSprites="false" Font-Size="11px" runat="server" CollapseDelay="0" ExpandDelay="0" ClickToOpen="true" ExpandAnimation-Type="None" CollapseAnimation-Type="None" CausesValidation="false"></telerik:RadMenu>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="content">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <div id="footer">
                    This is the footer
                </div>
            </div>
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS:

```
html,body 
{
    margin:5px;
    padding:0;
    height:100%; /* needed for container min-height */  
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#000000;
    background-color: #8FB1B1;  
    /*background-image: url(../../Images/Afbeelding1.jpg);*/
}

.formCss
{
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

div#container 
{
    position:relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
    margin:0 auto; /* center, not in IE5 */
    width:100%;     
    height:auto !important; /* real browsers */
    height:100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/
    min-height:100%; /* real browsers */

    background-color: #FFFFFF;  
}

div#headerContainer
{
    background-color: #8FB1B1;
}
div#header 
{
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-top: 12px;  
    height: 30px;   
    background-color: #1C2948;  /*#833D62;*/
    z-index: 100;
}


div#content 
{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top:10px;   
    background-color: #FFFFFF; /* #E0E5D7; #FFFFFF;*/
    padding-bottom:25px;  /* bottom padding for footer */

    /*filter:alpha(opacity=80); 
    -moz-opacity:0.80; 
    opacity:0.80;   */

}   

div#footer 
{
    position:absolute;
    height: 25px;   
    bottom:0; /* stick to bottom */
    background:#FFFFFF;     
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

I have put the code in a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7uuD6/1  
(It contains ASP.NET code that JSFiddle can't handle, unfortunately)

What am I doing wrong?
Cheers,
CJ

Comment: could you remove the code that isnt neceserry?  so i can implant it for you

Comment: You've made a total mess of your markup, so now the `#footer` is within several positioned parents itself, as such making it not work. Read up on how CSS positioning, and specifically `relative` and `absolute` work. Fixing this is a full rewrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two methods you could use to maintain a sticky footer, they depend on your browser support though.

If you do not care about IE7 or Firefox versions earlier than 17 you can use this approach which uses the box-model border-box property.

[Border-box Version](http://jsfiddle.net/fV3UH/)

For this you will only need two elements.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="page">    
</div> 
<div class="page-footer">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    /* Fix the box model to include padding */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.page {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -150px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
}

.page-footer {
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

If you need to support older browsers then you will need to use an extra div to push the footer down.

[Legacy Version](http://jsfiddle.net/SDNET/)

The code you will need for this version is as follows.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="page">
    <div class="page-push">
        <!--
            This div just pushes the footer down so content does not overflow it
        -->
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="page-footer">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.page {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -150px;
}

.page-push,
.page-footer{
    height:150px;
}

.page-footer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Your border-boxed version works great! Thanks I do have an additional question: I have turned it into this: http://jsfiddle.net/cjscholten/nnEXC/ and I was wondering: how can I adapt this so there is a 5px margin on the top and bottom that has the body background-color? (light-blue)

Comment: I've updated your code and added that behaviour. You needed to separate your `html` and `body` declarations with the padding on the `body` and add a rounded corner to your `.page` element also.

http://jsfiddle.net/nnEXC/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works great now.
There's just one tiny snag: because of the new padding the page always extends beyond the screen a tiny bit, adding a scrollbar even when the page itself is virtually empty. Any idea how I can counter this? I've tried editing various paddings and margins, but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, my mistake. With the extra padding it is best to move the box model fix to cover all elements. Here's an update that works.

http://jsfiddle.net/nnEXC/2/

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm! I have one more question: If the page contents expand (because of client-side things), the footer won't move down until a postback. Is there anything that can be done about this? (If not, no big deal)

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know I'm afraid. I would have to do some tests.

Comment: Hm, the problem seems to be limited to IE and Firefox.

Comment: Maybe try and set a min-height?

Comment: Any ideas on how to get the footer to reposition itself after a partial postback has stretched the page beyond the footer? (The contents of an update panel can grow, but the footer will stay in its place, hovering over the content)

Answer (score 0):

For that I recommend this: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

```
div#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
div#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
div#content {

   padding-bottom:___px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
div#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:___px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

if you apply and adjust to your html/css it wil lwork fine.

**//NOTE//** 
It is a risk to use a absolute footer!

Comment: Word of note. Prefixing an Id selector with an element type is unnecessary.

Comment: @JamesSouth i know but i adjusted it to his style ;)

Comment: No worries... Hopefully the op will realize that. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this jquery

[Sticky Footer jquery](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/)

Comment: There's absolutely no need to do this in JavaScript.

Comment: @JamesSouth doesnt mean you have to vote-down. it is a solution but its indeed not neceserry

Comment: It's an incorrect answer linking to an article written four years ago where the comments list bugs. A link that could theoretically disappear at any time. It also mixes concerns by using JavaScript to do a job that can be done easily with CSS which could cause a potential nightmare for following developers. What is worthy of a down-vote if not that?